# DIV stick when you scroll in dojotoolkit

Tags: scroll, dojo

How could create a div sticky in the dojotoolkit?
Some scroll function?

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/dom-geometry/position.html#dojo-dom-geometry-position

Answer (score 0):

You could indeed create an event handler to the scroll event and continuously reposition the div, or you simply use CSS and add `position: fixed` to the div.

For example:

```css
body {
    min-height: 9000px;
}

.box {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    left: calc(50% - 50px);
    top: calc(50% - 50px);
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Even when you scroll this box stays centered</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but listen event scroll in dojo?
I'm not make in dojo.

Comment: Explain me first why you need an event scroll. Right now you only told us you want to make a div sticky, which you can do with plain CSS. No Dojo or no JavaScript is required. See the example above, what's missing?

Comment: I want div sticky active when scroll.
Example with jquery http://jsfiddle.net/livibetter/HV9HM/